# How to know IP address of remote users conected to domain computers?

Tags: server, remote-desktop

Imagine that someone else, finds out or steals the password of the remote user connected to a virtual machine, therefore at some point the valid user, gets a message essentially saying someone else logged into the session and kick him off, is there a way to view from which IP adress the Virtual Machine was being accessed?

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-security/remote-desktop-connect-host-logs/1b578742-5222-41d0-9b0e-abc4893c7b7c ? Or maybe this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-networking/remote-desktop-connection-usage-log/5f10960f-8db2-42db-b0a4-a4a808cff966 ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @david i went in the right direction:

Solved my problem by using a PowerShell script shared by Mike Crowley:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Remote-Desktop-Connection-3fe225cd

Also, I found this amazing tool AdAudit that has many useful tools for managing and monitoring windows server environment

https://www.manageengine.com/products/active-directory-audit/

Thanks